# How to get new line in node JS and passing it as JSON and saving it in a text File

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Node Code

```
   var v = text1
        v = v + "\n"
        v = v + text2

     res.status(200).send(v);
                    return
```

I tried this but in my text file string are not seperated by new line
I have written this directive after getting the result in angular client

Angular Code

```
    $(anchor).attr({
        //href: 'data:text/json;charset=utf-8,' + JSON.stringify(data),                    
        href: 'data:text/json;charset=utf-8,' + (data.data),
        download: attr.filename
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer, The problem was with encoding data.

```
href: 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data)
```

Now I got the text file seperated by new line.

Answer (score 1):

Use a new **[ES6 interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** syntax:

```js
var v = 'Hello';
var text2 = 'World!'

v = `${v}
       ${text2}`;

console.log(v)
```

Comment: No its not working in text file still it is all string in new line

Comment: When i console.log(data);

Comment: Each string is seperated by new line but in my text File all the string in one line